# How can I make a function that will called from inside a loop and that will indicate whether to continue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, continue

```
def x():
    # Go through series of checks. Then in one of the conditional if statement.
    if y > x:
        return continue
        
while True:
    # Bunch of class attribute updates and checks.
    x()
```

When a function is called in a loop, if certain conditions are achieved, return a result that will make the loop go back to the beginning, as if a continue is being called.

Comment: Did you try writing it so that the function... returns some particular value... and then *let the loop check* whether that value was returned, and `continue` if so? It doesn't make sense to expect the function to be in control of the loop. The function has *no reason* to know that the loop *even exists*.

Answer (score 1):

Just take it as a variable:

```py
def x():
    # Go through series of checks. Then in one of the conditional if statement.
 
    if y > x:
        return True
        
while True:
    # Bunch of class attribute updates and checks.

    should_continue = x()
    if should_continue: 
        continue
```

Answer (score -1):

make a function that return a boolean variable , then after that function invocation use  if to check the variable
let's make an example to clarify:

you have this function

```
x(){

    var check=false;
    ...
    do something
    ...
    if(num==5){
      check=true;
    }

    return check;
}
```

your loop must be something like this:

```
while(true){

  ...
  ...
  stop=x()
  if(stop==false){
    group of instructions you want to skip
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }


}
```

Comment: While you seem to have the logic right, the question was for Python, and this code isn't valid Python.